# Very simple if/else statements seem to be working backwards

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script

I have been looking at this simple if/else statement in another larger project and I can't seem to find what I am doing wrong.

I have inserted Logger.log() in both if statements to try to root out the problem.

When I run the code, I get the following Log:

[19-02-24 08:50:05:427 PST] var Campus = Baylor

[19-02-24 08:50:05:428 PST] var TSTCCampus = TSTC

[19-02-24 08:50:05:428 PST] if IS= statement executed

[19-02-24 08:50:05:428 PST] else NOT= executed

The two variables are clearly NOT equal but the if = executes and the else != executes.

What am I doing wrong?

```
function myFunction() {

// call the Current Reults sheet and identify the Last Row of Responses
  var RawFormResponsesSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Current Results");
  var CurrentSubmission = RawFormResponsesSheet.getLastRow(); // Retruns the Value of the Last Submission Row Number
  var Campus = RawFormResponsesSheet.getRange(CurrentSubmission,3).getValue();

// call the Email Data sheet and identify certain cell values
  var EmailDataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Email Data")
  var TSTCCampus = EmailDataSheet.getRange(3, 4).getValue();
  var BaylorCampus = EmailDataSheet.getRange(4, 4).getValue();

Logger.log("var Campus = " + Campus)
Logger.log("var TSTCCampus = " + TSTCCampus)

if (Campus = TSTCCampus){Logger.log ("if IS= statement executed")}
else {Logger.log ("else IS= executed")}

if (Campus != TSTCCampus){Logger.log ("if NOT= statement executed")}
else {Logger.log ("else NOT= executed")}

}
```

Comment: I think you need `if (Campus == TSTCCampus) { ` instead of a single =

Comment: Tom, I edited my question to add Google Apps Script.
But, the == actually did the trick. Can you explain please?
I have done a number of if/else statements with the = and != and they worked.

Comment: Take a look at [this page - Comparison and Logical Operators](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp). It explains it well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `==` as comparison operator.

There are 3 = operators/commands:

- `=` is used to set the value of a variable
- `==` equality operator, returns `true` if the elements have same value, performs type conversion
- `===` identity operator, similar to `==`, but no type conversion

The following explains what type conversion is.

```
"5" == "5" returns true
"5" ==  5  returns true
"5" === "5" returns true
"5" ===  5  returns false
```

`somevar = 5` assigns and returns 5, which is a truthy value, and thus `if (x = 5) {` will always execute the conditional body. Similarly `if (x = 0) {` will never execute the conditional body, because it assigns and returns 0, which is falsy.

Comment: If you have an example where = works as logical operator, please show me.